# how do you evaluate times to in if statements in R

Tags: r

```
library(chron)
t<-times(c("03:00:00"))

dput(s)
structure(list(Description = "ServerA", Value = 173.59), .Names = c("Description", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 9L)
```

I am trying to execute this if statment against this data frame to create a Status column:

```
if(s$Description %in% c("ServerA") & (t>times(c("23:59:59")) & t<times(c("05:00:00"))) & s$Value<500){
    s$Status<-c("Green")
}
```

Does not work. Any Idea what I am missing here? Is my if stament valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works, however, it doesnt add/change a status in `s` because it is false. This is because you have two conditions for `t`: it should be greater than 23:59:59 and at the same time less than 05:00:00. But in your case it is not greater than 23:59:59. You can figure that out by running each if-condition separately.

Comment: @beginnR, I need to have t>times(c("23:00:00")) & t<times(c("05:00:00")) in the same line, any ideas how would do this?

Comment: @user1471980 No - that's an impossible condition. You're asking for a number that's greater than 23 AND less than 5.

Comment: basically I need to check for the time and value, if the t is between these times, and the value is this, create a status column.

Comment: @user1471980 Senor O is right. If you need to do this kind of condition, you would probably have to include dates, so that you can reference the previous day for example

Comment: @user1471980 another way is to simply modify the condition to t>=times(00:00:00), which would work

Comment: @user1471980 I think what you want is `t > times("23:00:00") | t < times("05:00:00")`.